# Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected -CentOS7

Tags: centos, centos7

When i visit https://extensions.gnome.org/

I have the latest Centos7 build and updated, i installed the addon ( both on firefox and chrome) and i still get this message..

In the documentation where it explains how to cmake the native connector and install it - when i tried to build it it gave me a error log:

```
The system is: Linux - 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 - x86_64
```

I don't know what else to do...

I also run `yum install gnome-shell-extension*`, `yum install gnome-shell-extension`, `and yum install gnome-shell`

Please help, i am new to Linux